# React js time conversion in time dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I need to display below options in material UI dropdown

from 5 to 60 dropdown should display 5m,10m,15m,20m,,and so on and for 720 and 1440 it should display 12h and 24h
I am using below code to set state in react

```
` let timeoption = "5,10,15,20,25,30,40,45,60,720,1440";
 setTimeOption(timeoption.split(',').map(option => {
    return {
        id: option,
        label: `${option}m`
    }
}));`
```

for 720,1440 label should display in "h" instead of "m"

`let timeoption = "5,10,15,20,25,30,40,45,60,720,1440"; setTimeOption(timeoption.split(',').map(option => { return { id: option, label:` ${option}m `} }));`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ternary operator in label to assign `m` or `h` based on the time value.

```js
let timeoption = "5,10,15,20,25,30,40,45,60,720,1440";
setTimeOption(timeoption.split(',').map(option => ({
    id: option,
    label: `${option}${option <= 60 ? 'm' : 'h'}`
})));
```

this is the output produced:

```js
[
  { id: '5', label: '5m' },
  { id: '10', label: '10m' },
  { id: '15', label: '15m' },
  { id: '20', label: '20m' },
  { id: '25', label: '25m' },
  { id: '30', label: '30m' },
  { id: '40', label: '40m' },
  { id: '45', label: '45m' },
  { id: '60', label: '60m' },
  { id: '720', label: '720h' },
  { id: '1440', label: '1440h' }
]
```

Comment: probably it would be better to set the label like `label: (option <= 60 ? \`${option}m\` : \`${option / 60}h\`);` to handle the hour issue